# User is returning null even after modifying it with context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am making an API call using Axios and after that I am send those details to context API but I am getting null. I am using formik to send data to backend and on submit of that form I make an api call using axios then get the user from backend end pass it on to context API.

UserContext

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import UserReducer from "./UserReducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
};

export const UserContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  const setUser = (userDetails) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_USER",
      payload: userDetails,
    });

    // Here it is returning the user data but INITIAL_STATE.user is null
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        setUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

UserReducer

```
    const UserReducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_USER":
          return {
            user: action.payload,
          };
    
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
    
    export default UserReducer;
```

Login

```
const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    onSubmit: () => {
      const getUser = async () => {
        const userData = await Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
          email: formik.values.email,
          password: formik.values.password,
        });

        setUser(userData.data); // Here I am sending the data to context API
      };
      getUser();
    },
    validationSchema,
  });
```

Comment: maybe you consume user data before it gets set. that's why you got null because user is null initially.

Comment: Does this happen when you refresh after logging in